# Не парсится json в android?

Tags: java, android, json

Не понимаю почему не могу получить содержания ключа.
Отрабатывает блок catch.
Что я делаю не так?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txt1;
//{"Sensor":{ "name":"Accelerometer","value":"-0,6    5,3   8,3"},{ "name2":"Orintation","value2":"0,0    0,0   0,0"} }
public static final String JSON_STRING = "{\"Sensor\":\n" +
       "\t{ \"name\":\"Accelerometer\",\n" +
       "\t  \"value\":\"-0,6\t\t5,3\t\t8,3\"\n" +
       "\t},\n" +
       "\t{ \n" +
       "\t\t\"name2\":\"Orintation\",\n" +
       "\t\t\"value2\":\"0,0\t\t0,0\t\t0,0\"\n" +
       "\t} \n" +
       "} ";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

}

public void myAction(View view){

    myJSONParse();
}

private void myJSONParse() {

    try{
        JSONObject jObj=(new JSONObject(JSON_STRING)).getJSONObject("Sensor");
        String str=jObj.getString("name");

        txt1.setText(str);

    }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

 }
}
```

> Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()

Как его правильно парсить ?

Comment: а у вас JSON не валидный... http://jsonlint.com/ тут проверьте `},{` явно что-то не то. Или это массив?

Comment: это не массив ,даже не знаю где может быть ошибка,а что там не так с валидностью?

Comment: а мне кажется массив. `{
 "Sensor": [{
  "name": "Accelerometer",
  "value": "-0,6    5,3   8,3"
 }, {
  "name2": "Orintation",
  "value2": "0,0    0,0   0,0"
 }]
}` Тогда и писать надо не `getJSONObject` а `getJSONArray` или как-то так

Comment: нет я специально комментировал оригинальную строчку                             {"Sensor":{ "name":"Accelerometer","value":"-0,6    5,3   8,3"},{ "name2":"Orintation","value2":"0,0    0,0   0,0"} }     тут без массива!

Comment: ещё раз говорю... Это не валидный JSON. Исправьте его.